# Let X be a random variable and consider an event A = {X > 3}. Condition on event A, is X deterministic or still random?

Tags: probability

When conditioning on A (meaning that my whole space is reduced to the event A), X is definitely greater than 3, but can I treat X as deterministic now?
I think it is still random, but not 100% sure.

(I'm asking because I want to compute Var(X|A), and if it is fixed then Var(X|A) = 0).

Thanks!

Comment: Well, what is $X$? That seems like it might be important. (I know it's a random variable, but what more can you tell us about it, if anything?)

Comment: Say X is a standard Normal. (But why would the answer be different?)

Comment: Well, if $X$ were a random variable with range $\{3,4\},$ for example, then $X\mid A$ is deterministic, since it may take only one value. Since $X$ is standard normal, though, there are infinitely-many possible values it may take on, even after conditioning.

Comment: Upshot: Look up (and then calculate) "conditional variance."